# Is it possible to scrape javascript graphs like this one?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I need to scrape historical market rates of freight from differing origins and destinations. Currently, I only have interactive graphs like this available to me:

Sample Graph

[image: Sample Graph]

You have to click on the graph to get the numbers to appear (all of them appear at once).

I have some experience with HTML web scraping through the Scrapy library, but I was wondering if something like BeautifulSoup would be capable of handling this type of problem.

Comment: You did not provide any technical details.

Comment: first you need `requests` to get HTML or JSON from server. If you get JSON then you don't need BeautifulSoup which only parse HTML/XML. Probably many graphs in JavaScript use JSON format to get data from server. You have to only find url to this JSON data.

Comment: @KlausD. my apologies, I am by no means a professional (or even an amateur programmer). What kind of technical details would be helpful in questions such as these?

Comment: @furas Great! I'll look into that

Comment: details like your current attempt at coding this and ideally the url. Please see [ask] and [mcve] for guidance on posting.

Comment: It's a good question but it would nice if you provided concrete website example.

Answer (score 4):

To put it shortly - yes but it depends.

Most javascript graphs work by embeding json data in `<script>` tags or making ajax request for it. So there is graph data in json format somewhere - you just need to find it.

To find it you should first open up page source and ctrl+f for some keypoints you see in the graph. In your case start with `£407` - it's very likely it's in embeded json:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{'prices': ['£407',...]}
</script>
```

Alternative it could also be retrieved as AJAX request. For example take this `craft.co` case. When you load https://craft.co/netflix page it makes AJAX request for graph data:

[image]

Comment: The data for the graph is coming from somewhere. As [@Granitosaurus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3737009/granitosaurus) said it should be embedded into the HTML or received from an external API request. You can discover this by looking at the HTML and looking at the network tab under XHR. Besure to have preserve logs and disable cache checked when refreshing to be sure you get the data again.